# Parsing double dimension array in controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is passing double dimension array to controller and again in controller convert the parameter string to double dimension array or list/datatable. Hence for reference, i am giving the code which describes, how i am passing the value to controller. But in controller, i am unable to convert string parameter to list/ datatable.

```
var rowData = {};
rowData [0]["PK"] = "1234";
rowData [0]["index"] = 1;
rowData [1]["PK"] = "2345";
rowData [1]["index"] = 2;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Test/TestAction",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'ID': JSON.stringify(rowData)

    }),
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
```

**MVC Controller Code**

In controller i am receiving ID parameter formatted as bellow,

```
{"0":{"PK":238484,"index":1},"1":{"PK":238506,"index":2}}
```

But in controller i am unable to convert this string parameter to list/ datatable.

```
public ActionResult TestAction(string ID){
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ObjectName= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(JSONString);
```

In order to install JSON.NET, go to "Manage NuGet Packages..." and search for JSON.NET or Newtonsoft.JSON. You can also install it through the Package Manager Console:
You Can also learn more from [here](http://www.ojdevelops.com/2016/05/converting-json-data-into-c-objects.html).

Comment: Hi Sushil, Thanks for your reply. In my "JSONString" variable,  I am having
{"0" {"PRIMARY_KEY":238426,"RowIndex":1},                                              "1":{"PRIMARY_KEY":238446,"RowIndex":2}}
Kindly let me know, how to convert the same back to List.

Comment: It's okay @TanushreeMukherjee. Did you get your answer??

Answer (score 0):

Your data is serialized as an object, or associative array if you wish. This can be deserialized as `Dictionary` on server side. You could do this manually with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, but why don't you let the modelbinder do its work?

```
public class Item
{
   [JsonProperty("PK")]
   public string PrimaryKey { get;set; }
   [JsonProperty("index")]
   public int Index { get;set; }
}

public ActionResult TestAction(IDictionary<string, Item> items){
  var asEnumerable = items.Select(x => x.Value);
  ....
}
```

By the way, if you would use array instead of object, you would get a list directly:

```
var rowData = [];
rowData.push( { PK:"1234", index: 1} );
rowData.push( { PK:"2345", index: 2} );
```

And on server-side:

```
 public ActionResult TestAction(IList<Item> items){
 ...
 }
```

And at least: don't use `asnyc: false`as it is deprecated and will be removed away someday soon.